# Getting the value of a hidden input field is undefined

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following code:

```
$.infinitescroll.prototype.pageNumber = $("#pagenumber_" + selector).val();
alert($.infinitescroll.prototype.pageNumber);
```

The alert says undefined. Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pagenumber_.category-dj" value="20">
```

When I do an alert like this:

```
alert("#pagenumber_" + selector);
```

These match, why is my val() coming up as undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A period `.` indicates a class in a CSS selector. One option is use an attribute selector instead to select the element by ID.

```
$("[id='pagenumber_" + selector + "']").val();
```

Comment: The attribute selector is slower than selecting by `id`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `.` as this has a special meaning in a jquery selector.  It needs to be `\\.`.

Comment: This is not jQuery specific actually, its how CSS selectors work in general. A word preceded by a `.` just indicates a class. So if you want to use `.` literally, it has to be escaped.